# Настройка загрузки модели, точнее создание экземпляра после загрузки

Tags: sqlalchemy

Хотелось бы узнать как это можно реализовать на sqlalchemy. Ну например я хочу сделать какую то обработку данных, или выбрать менеджер для поведения класса, в зависимости от содержимого полей.

Насколько я понял sqlalchemy, во время загрузки данных использует дефолтный конструктор класса, и писать какие-то опереции в **init** нет смысла.